# Policy Injection Application Block in real world apps?

Tags: .net, performance, enterprise-library, application-blocks, policy-injection

The PIAB of the Microsoft Enterprise Library looks like it could be used for some pretty cool things.  Many people were questioning how it would perform in real world applications, due to its use of remoting-based interception techniques.  I haven't heard much about it recently and am wondering if anyone has had good or bad experiences from a performance standpoint to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, not a single response in over a year.  I guess that's my answer!

Comment: You could always start a bounty if you really need an answer.  Your question only got 180 views.