# Policy Injection with Unity as AOP solution

Tags: unity-container, aop, policy-injection

This is the path our company is looking at as a solution for AOP (cross-cutting concerns), but I still have not been able to find any current feedback or samples/real-world examples of this methodology, only posts that are three or four years old.  This makes me a little nervous:

[Policy Injection Application Block in real world apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883465/policy-injection-application-block-in-real-world-apps)

Does this mean few are using Unity / Policy Injection in this way (more likely), or that it works so perfectly that no one needs to comment on it (highly UNlikely)?

If someone can point me to more current and relevant posts or articles on this subject, I would be most appreciative.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: If you're looking in applying cross-cutting concerns, take a look at how to apply them using decorators first before using interception or code weaving. Take a look [here](http://bit.ly/s7tGEH), [here](http://bit.ly/s3UUyv), and [here](http://bit.ly/RrJRvD) for instance.

Comment: I have done my best to politic for a different approach, but unfortunately it is not up to me, I don't really have a lot of choice except to use Unity. Should I take from your comment that it is uncommon for companies to use interception and policy injection to accomplish AOP? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how many developers use Unity's policy injection. Unity does allow you do apply decorators btw.